# Active directory automatic login to SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, active-directory, ssrs-2012

I have a server running SSRS 2012 at address `server1.olddomain.com`. This is working fine.

My users will be accessing this server from another address (the server is not physically moving). The new address is `server2.newdomain.net`. I modified the UriRoot option in the config file, and it works fine, except users are now prompted for their username and password through AD rather than being logged in automatically. (Once they enter their username and password in the form olddomain\username, they are logged in successfully).

How can I configure this to log users in automatically? The users' domain hasn't changed, nor has the server moved physical locations. Is this possible to do?

EDIT: I wasn't sure whether to post on here or ServerFault. Let me know if you think it would be better suited there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a simple matter of Internet Explorer not automatically detecting server2.newdomain.net as an "intranet" site. By default, IE will only do automatic Windows authentication in the intranet zone.

To see if this is the case, you can add "server2.newdomain.net" to the list of trusted intranet sites. Open IE, and do this:

1. Go to Tools, Internet Options.
2. Go to the Security tab, click Local intranet, and click the Sites button.
3. Click Advanced to open the list of sites.
4. Enter the full name ("server2.newdomain.net") into the appropriate box, and click Add.

If this gets automatic login working, then you'll have to decide how you want to solve the issue. You can specify a list of sites for the trusted intranet zone via Group Policy, but this prevents users from being able to add or remove anything on that particular list. If there's a cleaner way to do it, I'd be interested in knowing too, as we run into this a lot with intranet sites on various DNS domains.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give this a shot tomorrow at work and let you know :)

Comment: Yes, that did it. I think I'll see if it can get set up via Group policy, I don't think users have the ability to change that stuff anyway.

Comment: Users can typically configure that list if it's not being pushed out via GP, but you probably don't want to talk them all through the procedure. :)

Comment: I meant our users, I think our GP already disables that. At any rate, I don't know of anyone who does, so the GP solution is fine for our purposes.